# Error when trying to use Processing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I'm trying to run a Process PApplet in Eclipse and following directions here:
https://riptutorial.com/processing/example/31227/using-processing-with-eclipse

```
package testProcessing;

import processing.core.PApplet;


public class UsingProcessing extends PApplet {

    public UsingProcessing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        PApplet.main("testProcessing.UsingProcessing");
    }

    public void settings() {
        size(400,400);
    }

    public void setup() {
        background(0);
        stroke(255);
        strokeWeight(10);
    }

    public void draw() {
        line(0,0,200,200);
    }

}
```

But it keeps throwing this error, repeatedly endlessly and can't get around it.

```
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10846)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10657)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10639)
    at makerplot.UsingProcessing.<init>(UsingProcessing.java:10)
```

help? Thanks!

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I resolved this, with a copy/paste. Must have been a typo somewhere. Sorry and thanks!